# JIRA tally all logged work from linked issues and sub tasks to single issue

Tags: groovy, server, scripting, jira

I have tried several different groovy script methods form various examples as I am not a coder, but have come close but no real success.  I have thrown my hands up and am wondering if some smart person out there knows how to do this.

I simply need to show all total work logged for a specific link type of parent issues and their sub tasks  to a single issue as a grand total.  See diagram.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correcting the posted answer:

This got answered for me from another community member here: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Questions/JIRA-tally-all-logged-work-from-linked-issues-and-sub-tasks-to/qaq-p/1434260#U1435384

The script provided that worked for me was the following:

```
// Template: Duration (either of the 2)

import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor

def issueLinkmanager = ComponentAccessor.getIssueLinkManager()
def subtaskManager = ComponentAccessor.getSubTaskManager()
def workLogManager = ComponentAccessor.getWorklogManager()

def linkName = "Work"


def linkCollection = issueLinkmanager.getLinkCollectionOverrideSecurity(issue)
def linkedIssues = linkCollection?.getInwardIssues(linkName) //Inward or Outward? Verify and change if needed.

if (!linkedIssues) {
    // no linked issues
    return null
}

def totalTimeSpentFromWorkLinkedIssuesAndTheirSubtasks = []

for (def linkedIssue:linkedIssues) {
    def worklogList = workLogManager.getByIssue(linkedIssue)
    for (def worklog:worklogList) {
        def timeSpent = worklog.getTimeSpent()
        totalTimeSpentFromWorkLinkedIssuesAndTheirSubtasks.add(timeSpent)
    }

    def subTasks = subtaskManager.getSubTaskObjects(linkedIssue)
    for (def subTask:subTasks) {
        def worklogListSubTask = workLogManager.getByIssue(subTask)
        for (def worklogSubTask:worklogListSubTask) {
            def timeSpent = worklogSubTask.getTimeSpent()
            totalTimeSpentFromWorkLinkedIssuesAndTheirSubtasks.add(timeSpent)
        }
    }
}

return totalTimeSpentFromWorkLinkedIssuesAndTheirSubtasks?.sum()
```